# VBA Macro triggered by cell change with a dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I encounter a small issue when combining the automatic on change cell value feature with a dropdown list.

What I want is to have a macro launched everytime I change the value of a specific cell on my excel sheet. This cell has a dropdown list.

The problem I have is that for the moment, the macro is launched when I click on the cell but not necesseraly when the value of the cell changes. In fact, I don't have the opportunity to edit the value of the cell, the macro is already executed before that.

The code I use is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  Call MyMacro

  Range("A1").Select

  Application.EnableEvents = True

 End if

End Sub
```

A1 is a dropdown list with 3 values. MyMacro pastes different types of information depending on the selected value in the dropdown list. I found that it was necessary to turn off EnableEvents to avoid unneccessary loops. I also have to select the cell A1 in the end of my code to be able to effectively change the value in the cell A1 (otherwise, it just launches the macro without letting me edit the value of the cell).

I hope the problem is clear. The code gives some results but not exactly what I expect. I have checked the other topics on the subject and some discussions are close to my problem but I don't find a solution.

Comment: FYI `Worksheet_Change` only fires when a cells' value is changed manually or via code.  It won't fire if there's a formula in (eg) A1 and it recalculates.  "the macro is launched when I click on the cell" - sounds like you have some code in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event?  That event is for when cells are selected, not for when their values change.

Comment: You are totally right. That was my problem. My god, it was so silly :o. I spent hours looking for the solution. Thanks a lot!